# How to publish aar file to Apache Archiva with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, archiva, aar

I´m trying to publish the generated **aar** file of my android library to my Apache Archiva Maven server, but I haven´t manage to get it working yet because either the examples are outdated 
or they are for **java** and not for **android**

After noticing that most methods of the gradle examples are deprecated, I found this new documentation:

[Gradle Documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Which describes how to use the new API which seems to replace **uploadArchives** with **publishing** and so on....

So this is what I´ve got so far:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mycompany.mylibrary"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}

publishing {

publications {
    mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
        groupId 'com.android.mylibrary'
        artifactId 'MyLibrary'
        version '1.0.0'

        from components.java

        artifact sourceJar {
            classifier "sources"
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url "myurl"
        credentials{
            username "user"
            password "password"
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Gradle stuff is like the hell for me. I don´t know what is right and what is wrong and some things seem to be changed without any hints that it isn´t supported anymore, which makes it quite difficult to solve these problems...

**How can I automatically upload the generated aar file to my Apache Archiva?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solved it by myself

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   provided 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
   provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
   classifier "source"
}

publishing {
   publications {

       repositories.maven {
           url 'myurl/repositories/myrepo'
           credentials {
               username "user"
               password "password"
           }
       }

       maven(MavenPublication) {
           artifacts {
               groupId 'com.mycompany'
               artifactId 'mylibrary'
               version '1.0'
               artifact 'build/outputs/aar/app-release.aar'
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: What a simple and effective solution. Worked like charm :)

Comment: But this won't build proper pom.xml file, you will miss depndency data and that useless

Comment: It has nothing to do with the build process, it just uploads the aar to your server. You might have another problem elsewhere

Comment: Answer does **NOT WORK** properly. Basically as pointed out by outlying you won't get a auto generated pom.xml from this approach which will render the resulting aar useless.

Comment: I was using this in production for over two years now. I don´t see any problem related to a missing pom.xml. Why do you need that? @uniqueentity

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Android Studio and therefore had also upgrade the ever-fragile unique snowflake that is gradle to version 8, i.e.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

This upgrade broke my setup, here's my fix, where I upload the release aar to  our internal maven repo server (could be archiva, could be nexus, etc.); to upload you'd need to run the '**publishCrazyClownBehaviourPublicationToMavenRepository**' task.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

android {
    namespace = "die.gradle.die.please.lib"
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    // this is important, scopes the build to the 'release' target/artifact
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") 
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {

            repositories.maven {
                url "https://your.maven.repo/goes/here/"
                credentials {
                    username "crazy"
                    password "clown"
                }
            }

            crazyClownBehaviour(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release {
                    artifacts {
                        groupId 'die.gradle.die.please.lib'
                        artifactId 'die_gradle_die_please_lib'
                        version '6.6.6'
                        artifact 'build/outputs/aar/app-release.aar'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

}
```

Greetz to the Gradle clown community, please lookup: backwards compatibility, tight coupling and colourful hats!