# How do I host Github repository to Gradle

Tags: android, github, android-studio, repository, android-gradle-plugin

I have a repository on Github, I would like to use my repository in Android Studio using: dependencies {compile 'com.google.code.gson: Gson: 2+'} for gradle. Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I really got the question...I understood that you want to compile some jar files that are not local to your project and are hosted in your repository. If it is the matter, I guess you should use a custom maven repository, not a Github one. If this is the problem I can give you more details on how to create a custom maven repo.

Comment: Hello, I want to use my repository (which is an Android library) that are hosted on github, in another project, as when we import for an Android project Gson the library, for example
dependencies {compile 'com.google.code.gson: Gson: 2 +'}

Answer (score 6):

You could use [JitPack.io](http://jitpack.io) to expose your repository as a Maven dependency. Then including it in Android Studio is easy with gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.YourUsername:RepoName:ReleaseVersion'
```

There are more instructions on the website.

Comment: Do you know if this works with BitBucket? And if we can use a private repository? @Andrejs

Comment: @DavidCesarSantos Private GitHub repos, yes. For BitBucket: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/25

Comment: I will wait for the BitBucket features. Thanks!

Comment: hey, I test JitPack with GitHub and is not easy to use. I have all the time an error. Do you have a sample? The samples of the web site isn't clear

Comment: @DavidCesarSantos why dont you open a github issue with the error? there's also a chat for discussing issues

Answer (score -1):

It's like @dometheshooter said.

See:

- [How to publish aar file to Apache Archiva with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676838/how-to-publish-aar-file-to-apache-archiva-with-gradle)
- [Guide to publish an aar to maven using gradle](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-guide-to-publish-aar-to-maven-gradle.html)
- [How to deploy JAR to Maven remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501447/how-to-deploy-jar-to-maven-remote-repository)
- [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html)
- [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html)